# pst-infixplot with babel puts unintended comma sign at the beginning

Tags: packages, pstricks, babel, punctuation

I had unintended comma sign at the beginning of the document. If I comment out the `babel` package or `pst-infixplot` package, then comma sign disappeared. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-infixplot}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Replacing `[turkish]` with any language or changing the order of packages results same problem.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I am using MikTeX on 64-bit Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't have `pst-infixplot` installed, but with the `pst-plot` package (for which the option `[algebraic]`  is defined anyway, so I think pst-infixplot is obsolete) I have no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have just learned the [algebraic] option.

Answer (score 1):

The bug involves line 477 of file `infix-RPN.tex`:

```
\let\@nil\relax
```

You can reproduce it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\@nil\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

(for why it causes the comma in interaction with babel see bottom of post)

In details, the relevant code in `infix-RPN.tex` is

```
\let\@nil\relax

\def\compare@PS@operator#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname op@token\current@cnt\endcsname\@tempa%
    \advance\count1\@ne
    \search@primary{\the\count1}{\the\count255}%
    \advance\count1\m@ne
    \@tokenuse{\the\count1}%
  \fi
  \ifx\@tempb\empty
    \let\next\relax
    \let\@tempb\relax
  \else
    \let\next\compare@PS@operator
  \fi
  \expandafter\next\@tempb\@nil
}
```

One can fix the bug provoked by these definitions by adding this to preamble after loading the `pst-infixplot` package.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@nil\undefined

\def\compare@PS@operator#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname op@token\current@cnt\endcsname\@tempa%
    \advance\count1\@ne
    \search@primary{\the\count1}{\the\count255}%
    \advance\count1\m@ne
    \@tokenuse{\the\count1}%
  \fi
  \ifx\@tempb\empty
    \let\next\@gobble
  \else
    \let\next\compare@PS@operator
  \fi
  \expandafter\next\@tempb\@nil
}
\makeatother
```

Final part of analysis:

Here is why babel gets tripped if `\@nil` has meaning `\relax`.

One sees this in a macro trace:

```
\bbl@vforeach #1#2->\def \bbl@forcmd ##1{#2}\bbl@fornext #1,\@nil ,
#1<-LGR,X2,OT2,OT3,OT6,LHE,LWN,LMA,LMC,LMS,LMU,
#2<-\ifin@ \else \lowercase {\bbl@xin@ {,##1enc.def,}{,\@filelist ,}}\fi 

\bbl@fornext #1,->\ifx \@nil #1\relax \else \bbl@ifblank {#1}{}{\bbl@trim \bbl@
forcmd {#1}}\expandafter \bbl@fornext \fi 
#1<-LGR
```

This means we will have

```
\bbl@fornext LGR,X2,OT2,OT3,OT6,LHE,LWN,LMA,LMC,LMS,LMU,,\@nil ,
```

Notice the two commas. When the loop reaches the item after LMU, it is empty, so `\bbl@fornext #1,` gets an empty `#1` and leaves `\@nil ,` in token stream:

as `#1` is empty the test `\ifx \@nil #1\relax` compares `\@nil` and `\relax` and does not execute the `\else` branch. Because `\@nil` has same meaning as `\relax` due to bug in `infix-RPN.tex`. So there comes `\@nil ,` in token stream which results in a comma as first thing in output.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[...]
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-infixplot}
\makeatletter
\let\@nil\@empty
\makeatother
[...]
```

However, the solution with `algebraic` is easier and , of course, file a bug report to the authors.